# Does AWS EBS (Elastic Block Store) have its own internal caching system?

Tags: amazon-ebs

Hi I am interested to know some internal details about AWS EBS (Elastic Block Store) system. Does it have its own caching system? I mean, does EBS rely on OS's page cache, or it has its own internal caching system?

Comment: You can bet that it's entirely custom in-house, with layers of abstraction, performance tweaks, ways to load, shed load, etc.